# How to get list of breakpoints in Visual Studio programmatically?

Tags: visual-studio, breakpoints

Is there a way to get the list of all the breakpoints set in Visual Studio in debugged C++ application from the application itself?

*Note: scanning through the code for the presence of 0xCC byte won't do as the task is to get all the original bytes in places of set breakpoints. One of the solutions may actually include disassembling necessary code, then, if 0xCC encountered, looking at the original file and receiving original byte. But maybe VS offers the same functionality through one of its interfaces?*

Comment: Does it need to be in the application itself? Or can VS list them?

Comment: @Rakete1111 From the application itself, so that it executes some code and interacts with VS through one of provided interfaces (if it's at all possible).

Comment: Why do you need it from the application itself? Just curious :)

Comment: did not have time to research thoroughly right now, but may be worth a closer look: `ICorDebugBreakpointEnum` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms231023(v=vs.100).aspx. Or are you in non-managed code?

Comment: @Rakete1111 At some point of application run we need to make disassembly listing of a function where particular event occurs. Of course, if it has 0xCC bytes in it, the analysis will be irrelevant. There is a way to get original bytes back (see _note_ in the original post) but is it the only way?..

Comment: @dlatikay For now it is a non-managed code but if there is no other way then managed code can be added to the project to handle this particular situation. Thank you for the link, will investigate it.